# How to include user details in Access Token JWT Payload while implementing Auth Code Flow with PKCE with auth0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, auth0, pkce

I'm trying to work through implementing an Auth Code Flow with PKCE in a personal web application, and I'm stuck, so any help would be appreciated. The goal of the website is for a user to login (with OAuth2 from Auth0), and perform CRUD operations on some records which only the user has access to. The app is a React SPA with an express backend. The flow I'm trying to implement right now is:

1. User authenticates via frontend: Login via OAuth to retrieve Auth Code
2. We exchange Auth Code for an access token, set it as the Authorization header Bearer token
3. On the client, user creates a resource via POST call to server: On the backend, we validate the access token.
4. On the backend, we determine WHO the resource is; this is critical because I need to know which records belong to this user (this is basically where I'm stuck)
5. Record is created with that user's email_address as one of the columns

Right now the only way I know how to implement 4. is by having my server call this GET `/userinfo` API from auth0: https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication#user-profile. This allows me to get the email from the user's profile, but the HTTP call sometimes takes quite long (~500ms), and it just feels wrong to have to do this for every CUD operation.

I thought there would be a way to have user information included as a claim in the Access Token. I tried fiddling around with different `scope` values in my request for the Auth token, but none of them change the properties in the JWT's payload.

I would greatly appreciate anyone who takes the time to read this and perhaps provides a solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to add a custom claim to my Access Token containing the email:

https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/create-custom-claims